# JavaScript, map object in other object with possition

Tags: javascript

I need to create an object like this:

```
const needThis = {
  0: {
    LABEL: {
      A: 1,
      B: 2
    }
  },
  1: {
    OTHER_LABEL: {
      E: 1,
      B: 4
    }
  },
  // etc..., more objects with first key 3, 4, and so on
}
```

The data that I have is this:

```
const haveThis = {
  LABEL: {
    A: 1,
    B: 2
  },
  OTHER_LABEL: {
    E: 1,
    B: 4
  }
}
```

In other words, I have to create an object but putting as a key of each object the position of the `haveThis` object.

Here I'm trying:

```js
const needThis = {
  0: {
    LABEL: {
      A: 1,
      B: 2
    }
  },
  1: {
    OTHER_LABEL: {
      E: 1,
      B: 4
    }
  }
}
const haveThis = {
  LABEL: {
    A: 1,
    B: 2
  },
  OTHER_LABEL: {
    E: 1,
    B: 4
  }
}
const result = {}

const keys = Object.keys(haveThis)
const values = Object.values(haveThis)

keys.forEach((key, i) => {
  const inside = {}
  inside[keys[i]] = values[i]
  result[i] = inside
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I don't get it, you seem to have working code of the result you trying to accomplish already?

Comment: hm, sorry, I changed the jsfiddle before posting it, it's working now, but I wonder if there's a better solution

Comment: I would use [`entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the keys and values in pairs. Other then that your code seems to be totally fine. Voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

By modifying your code and using [computed property names](https://eloquentcode.com/computed-property-names-in-javascript#:%7E:text=Computed%20Property%20Names%20is%20an,be%20determined%20dynamically%2C%20i.e.%20computed.), this can be done like this:

```js
const needThis = {
  0: {
    LABEL: {
      A: 1,
      B: 2
    }
  },
  1: {
    OTHER_LABEL: {
      E: 1,
      B: 4
    }
  }
}
const haveThis = {
  LABEL: {
    A: 1,
    B: 2
  },
  OTHER_LABEL: {
    E: 1,
    B: 4
  }
}
const result = {}
const keys = Object.keys(haveThis)
//const values = Object.values(haveThis) // No need for this
keys.forEach((key, i) => {
  result[i] = { [key] : haveThis[key] };
})
console.log(result)
```

You can skip the `Object.values()`, if you simple want to use the keys from `haveThis`.

Also, you can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) directly too/

```js
 const needThis = {
      0: {
        LABEL: {
          A: 1,
          B: 2
        }
      },
      1: {
        OTHER_LABEL: {
          E: 1,
          B: 4
        }
      }
    }
    const haveThis = {
      LABEL: {
        A: 1,
        B: 2
      },
      OTHER_LABEL: {
        E: 1,
        B: 4
      }
    }
    const result = {}
    const entries = Object.entries(haveThis)
    //const values = Object.values(haveThis) // No need for this
    entries.forEach(([key, value],index) => {
      result[index] = { [key] : value };
      });
      
      console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const wrapKeyValuePair = (keyValuePair, index) => ([ index, { [keyValuePair[0]]: keyValuePair[1] } ]);
const getKeyValuePairs = (obj) => Object.entries(obj).map(wrapKeyValuePair);
Object.fromEntries(getKeyValuePairs(haveThis));
```